# Create a XML file from a trigger

Tags: sql, xml, firebird, firebird2.5

Here is the situation, I need to create a XML file every time a specific field from the table gets updated to "C" or "L". The Xml file needs to be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DATAPACKET Version="2.0">
  <METADATA>
    <FIELDS>
      <FIELD attrname="ID_COMAND" fieldtype="string" WIDTH="20" />
      <FIELD attrname="EVENT" fieldtype="string" WIDTH="1" />
    </FIELDS>
    <PARAMS />
  </METADATA>
  <ROWDATA>
    <ROW RowState="4" ID_COMAND="3721" EVENT="C" />
  </ROWDATA>
</DATAPACKET>
```

It's been very hard to find a way to do this, help me please.

Comment: Please provide more details: RDBMS (product and version), what does *create a XML file* mean? A phyiscally written file or just some XML to be stored somewhere in the database? Structure of the table...

Comment: Just a file, i'm using firebird 2.5.

Comment: Do you have a **specific question** like "I have created this stored procedure skeleton with all the info I need, but I don't know how to format it into an XML format"? Or "How can I write this XML fragment to a file/database table?"? Folks here are usually much more willing to help with specific problems (especially if you can demonstrate that you made an effort to try to solve the problem yourself) instead of "Please tell me how to write this code"

Comment: What's the part causing you difficulty - creating the file or creating the trigger?

Comment: Creating the trigger that creates the file.

Comment: Sry for the lack of information, i'm not used to work with triggers and never had to export information to XML from SQL before. But i've been searching it for hours and nothing came up tp help me.

Comment: Firebird itself has no support for XML built-in nor for creating files, so you either need to use string concatenation, and/or write a UDF that does the work for you. However as it stands, the question is too broad. Do you expect us to do everything for you? For writing triggers, see [Procedural SQL (PSQL) Statements](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-psql.html) in the Firebird language reference.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I just need a way, you are really helping just by giving me new information like the fact that there is no support for doing it directly.

Comment: `Creating the trigger that creates the file` - I don't like that idea. Your XML-creation DLL can meet all the various kinds of delays and OS/hardware errors, and bring them all back into SQL core. Not good. Personally i'd use the trigger to insert the record into some "needs logging" buffer table and then issue a `POST_EVENT` command to notify some external daemon program that would be fetching those "needs logging" records and flush them to XML and remove the processed rows from that buffer table afterwards.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel , I used an UDF, solved it, thnks.

Comment: You're welcome. You should consider posting your own solution as an answer.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel will be doing it soon.